# Super simple quiz program. My answers are not validating and score isn't ++ either

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I am writing this super simple javascript quiz for practice. I am frustrated because I think my code is correct, but my code is not working.

My answers are not 'validating' and I have no clue why. My score is still coming out as 0. My score is not score++ when it should..

The problem is in this snippet:

```
 for (var j = 0; j <= total.length; j++) {
    if (questionArray[j] === answers[j]) {
      score = score + 1;
    }
  }
```

JS:

```
function submitAnswers() {

  //Set score and total number of questions
  var total = 5;
  var score = 0;
  //Get user input for each question
  var q1 = document.forms['quizForm']['q1'].value.toString();
  var q2 = document.forms['quizForm']['q2'].value.toString();
  var q3 = document.forms['quizForm']['q3'].value.toString();
  var q4 = document.forms['quizForm']['q4'].value.toString();
  var q5 = document.forms['quizForm']['q5'].value.toString();

  //Load Questions into Question Array
  var questionArray = [q1, q2, q3, q4, q5];

  //Validation
  for (var i = 0; i <= questionArray.length; i++) {
    if (questionArray[i] === null || questionArray[i] === '') {
      alert("Oops!  You forgot to answer a question.  Please enter an answer for Question " + [i + 1] + ".");
      return false;
    }
  }


  //Set correct Answers
  var answers = ["b", "a", "d", "b", "d"];

  //Check for correct answers
  for (var j = 0; j <= total.length; j++) {
    if (questionArray[j] === answers[j]) {
      score = score + 1;
    }
  }
  alert("You scoreed "+ score+ " out of "+total);



  return false;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jeffward01/1y3dxk0s/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for validation part:

```
  for (var i = 0; i <= questionArray.length; i++)
```

should be

```
  for (var i = 0; i < questionArray.length; i++)
```

for answers part:

```
 for (var j = 0; j <= total.length; j++)
```

should be

```
 for (var j = 0; j < answers.length; j++)
```

Comment: That was a typo of mine from me messing around and troubleshooting the code.  I changed it to 'j' and it still doesn't work.  I will edit the question to reflect it.

Comment: Ok that fixed it.  Why would changing it from 'total.length' to 'anwers.length' have an impact??  Aren't they the same length so its not a factor.

Comment: well `total` is a number, it doesn't have a 'length"

Comment: ah.  that makes sense... Thank you.  Dumb mistake on my part.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
for (var j = 0; j < total.length; j++) {
```

to

```
for (var j = 0; j < total; j++) {
```

total is the value you want, not total.length.

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/1y3dxk0s/2/)**